# Crontab not working with a script in my Docker image

Tags: python, bash, docker, docker-compose, cron

I have a dockerfile:

```bash
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get -y install cron
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./collect_data.txt  /collect_data.txt
RUN chmod +x /collect_data.txt
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
COPY ./run_scraper.sh /run_scraper.sh
RUN chmod +x /run_scraper.sh
RUN crontab /collect_data.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "cron", "-f" ]
```

Also run_scraper.sh script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd ./scraper

scrapy crawl weather_spider
```

And cron task collect_data.txt:

```
* * * * * /run_scraper.sh

# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

For some reason the cron is not working. However, when I remove `ENTRYPOINT [ "cron", "-f" ]` from the Dockerfile, and in my docker-compose file I add `command: bash /run_scraper.sh` the script works just fine, but I need it to run every minute.

Is there anything wrong I'm doing in my files? How can I fix this?

My weather_spider looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import scrapy

from app.db.session import SessionLocal

from app import crud
from app import schemas


class ForecastSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "weather_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["openweathermap.org"]
    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        cities = crud.city.get_all(db=SessionLocal())
        for city in cities:
            self.start_urls.append(
                f"https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={city.name}&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02&units=metric"
            )
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    # parse the data from the response using the _extract_data method
    def parse(self, response):
        weather_data = self._extract_data(response.json())
        # convert the data to WeatherCreate object
        item_in = schemas.WeatherCreate(
            temperature=weather_data["temperature"],
            pressure=weather_data["pressure"],
            wind_speed=weather_data["wind_speed"],
            city_id=weather_data["city_id"],
        )
        # create a new weather record
        weather = crud.weather.create_with_city(
            db=SessionLocal(), obj_in=item_in, city_id=weather_data["city_id"]
        )

    @staticmethod
    def _extract_data(weather_data: dict) -> dict:
        """
        Extracts relevant data from the `weather_data` dictionary and returns it as a new dictionary.

        :param weather_data: A dictionary containing weather data from OpenWeatherMap API.
        :type weather_data: dict
        :return: A dictionary with the extracted data including city name, temperature, pressure and wind speed.
        :rtype: dict
        """
        data = weather_data["list"][0]

        city_id = data["id"]
        temperature = data["main"]["temp"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind_speed = data["wind"]["speed"]

        return {
            "city_id": city_id,
            "temperature": temperature,
            "pressure": pressure,
            "wind_speed": wind_speed,
        }
```

Where SessionLocal is:

```py
engine = create_engine(os.environ.get("POSTGRES_URL"), pool_pre_ping=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your collect_data.txt file to:

```
* * * * * /run_scraper.sh
```

And it should run fine. The default user in Dockerfile is root, so you don't have to switch users. And if you want to run script in bash, just add proper shebang - `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I updated the collect_data.txt to what you suggested. Still no result. However, when I open the container in terminal and type: service cron status; I get: cron is running.
crontab -l gives me: * * * * * /run_scraper.sh

# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.

Maybe the script is not running because I use env variables in my weather_spider?

Comment: I have updated the post with the latest code.